# Using FunctionQuery in SOLR Sort Syntax

Tags: solr, lucene

Our SOLR has an index of around 20000 products. The data model for these products is straightforward like below.

```
{name: "Foo", sales: 120, price: 20, desc: "lorem ipsum"}
```

What I'm trying to do is that instead of using the default sort order of `score desc` using a custom function like

```
sales x score
```

where the score is the SOLR relevance score. I've tried changing the sort parameters to `sort=product(sales, score)` which does not work as score is a pseudo field and not an indexed attribute.

Is there a function which I can use to reference the "score" field in SOLR? (i'm using SOLR 3.x)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`boost` parameter available in EDisMax](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#boost_.28Boost_Function.2C_multiplicative.29) - it'll multiply the boost directly into the score (instead of being additive as `bf` is). EDisMax is available from Solr 3.1.

If needed you can [use the `field` function](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#field) to return the value from a field with a function.